# Evaluating limit of a sum:$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n (a - {2j\over n})^3$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve this problem:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^n {(a - {2j\over n})^3\over n}$$

My first instinct was to do a substition $x = {1 \over n}$ and rewrite the problem as:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\sum_{j=1}^\infty {(a - {2jx})^3}x$$
Here it looks obvious that this is a Riemann sum that can be evaluated as an integral, but I'm stuck. I don't know how to calculate this as an integral. This is the best I could come up with:
$$\int_1^\infty {(a - {2jx})^3}dx$$
But I don't think it makes sense to evaluate at infinity for the upper bound. I think my integral is written wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any hints as to how to approach this problem properly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: a "right" Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx$ would be $$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{f(j/n)}{n}$$
Your sum looks like that; what is the function $f$?

Answer (score 3):

## *Hint:*

When $j$ changes from $1$ to $n$, then the term $\dfrac{j}{n}$ varies from $\dfrac{1}{n}$ to $1$, which leads to $0\leqslant x \leqslant 1.$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\left(a - \dfrac{2j}n \right)^3 & = a^3 - 3a^2\left( \dfrac{2j}n\right) + 3a\left( \dfrac{2j}n\right)^2 - \left( \dfrac{2j}n\right)^3\\
\sum_{j=1}^n \left(a - \dfrac{2j}n \right)^3 & = na^3 - 3a^2\left( \dfrac{n(n+1)}n\right) + 3a\left( \dfrac{2n(n+1)(2n+1)}{3n^2}\right) - \left( \dfrac{2n^2(n+1)^2}{n^3}\right)\\
& = na^3 - 3a^2(n+1) + a\left( \dfrac{2(n+1)(2n+1)}{n}\right) - \left( \dfrac{2(n+1)^2}{n}\right)\\
\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n \left(a - \dfrac{2j}n \right)^3}n & = a^3 - 3a^2(1+1/n) + a\left( 2(1+1/n)(2+1/n)\right) - \left( 2(1+1/n)^2\right)
\end{align}
Hence, your limit is
$$a^3 - 3a^2 + 4a-2 = (a-1)(a^2-2a+2)$$

Comment: +1 - I find this solution very elegant because it doesn't use integration.